# Xcode 7.3: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I install AFNetworking via CocoaPod, but when I run it says error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have cleaned my project and build again but not works.

If I remove `#import "MediaClient.h"` in `AppDelegate.h`, it works:

[image]

My `MediaClient.h` is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Media.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

NSString *movieURLString = @"abc";
NSString *dvdURLString = @"def";

typedef void (^Completion) (NSArray<Media*> *medias);

@interface MediaClient : NSObject

- (void)load:(MediaType *)mediaType completion:(Completion)completion;
- (void)loadMovies:(Completion)completion;
- (void)loadDVDs:(Completion)completion;
- (void)callAPI:(NSString *)urlString completion:(Completion)completion;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean your project properly by follow steps.

**1) Products > clean**

**2) Windows > Projects**

**3) Select your project and click on "Delete" derived Data**

**4) Products > Build**

and if you are running your project on actual device and facing that problem

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

then Please configure the ***Code Signing*** section in the ***Build Settings*** tab

In your Project Navigation select **Project > Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > No**

Comment: Please check my Edited Answer's Last line & Do let me know whether it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Select your Project in **ProjectNavigation>Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > No**

**if it works then good**

> otherwise

you should try this one permanent solution.Generally overwriting project may cause these problems. Try this method.

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In some case error log window displaying .xctest error, to fix it

1. Select your project
2. Beside this(just before General tab) select your projectTest file from dropdown
3. There is one option (like ProjNameTests)
4. In Host Application, select your project from dropdown only if it show custom

Image for Clarification purpose. 
[image]

Plz give me your feedback whether this is helpful or not!

Answer (score 0):

AS you stated in the title of your Question, **Linker Command Failed**

Sometime when we upgrade our Project to Xcode 7.3, the dependencies do not assume the architecture settings of the main project, as they previously did in some older version of Xcode. so please go through all of your dependencies setting and set those for the correct architecture.

The thing which I am trying to point out in my last paragraph & which **I noticed in your uploaded image file**, that your AFNetworking is not installed in your project via CocoaPods correctly. as your project's file Navigation area does not showing AFNetworking directory or its files references.

Please show me your `podfile` which you created & installed in your project directory

Your Podfile should look like this,

```
target 'JSONHandle' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

and never include any reference link in `podfile` which is stated in `AFNetworking` site in its installing instructions.

Comment: @Khuong, did you followed my instructions & any updates?